# setting up a one to many relationship for a self referencing table

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `Project` entity with a non-autogenerated id field and a successor field. This successor is the project that follows next. But maybe there is no following project so this might be null.

```
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })
  public id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Project, project => project.id, { nullable: true })
  public successorId?: string;
}
```

When creating a new project via

```
public createProject(id: string, successorId?: string): Promise<Project> {
  const project: Project = new Project();
  project.id = id;
  project.successorId = successorId;
  return project.save();
}
```

there are multiple cases I have to take care for.

- Passing in an id that already exists:

  This will not throw an error. It just overrides the existing entity.
- Passing in `undefined` for the `successorId`:

  The code works fine then but it does not create a `successorId` column with `null` then. The column simply does not exist in the database.
- Passing in the same id for `id` and `successorId` (this should be possible):

  TypeORM throws the error

  > TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined
- Passing in a `successorId` of another existing project:

  I'm getting the same error as above
- Passing in a `successorId` of a project that doesn't exist:

  I'm getting the same error as above

So how can I fix that? I think my entity design seems to be wrong. Basically it should be

- One project might have one successor
- A project can be the successor of many projects

Would be awesome if someone could help!

---

**Update**

I also tried this

```
@OneToMany(() => Project, project => project.successorId, { nullable: true })
@Column()
public successorId?: string;
```

but whenever I want to call the `createProject` method I'm getting this error

> QueryFailedError: null value in column "successorId" violates not-null
>   constraint

and this

```
@OneToMany(() => Project, project => project.successorId, { nullable: true })
public successorId?: string;
```

but then I'm getting this error

> TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try this solution

```
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })
  public id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public successorId?: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Project, project => project.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "successorId" })
  public successor?: Project;
}
```

`public successor?: Project;` - property is used for building relation between entities (same entity in this case). Related entity must be specified as a property type, because TypeORM uses this type to determine target entity and build relation metadata. You can read more about TypeORM relations [here](https://typeorm.io/#/relations)

`public successorId?: string;` - property is just an "extracted" join column. When you use `ManyToOne` relation, TypeORM automatically creates a column in the database named `propertyName` + `referencedColumnName` (`successorId` in this case). But you cannot use this column in your code, because it is defined only in table and not in your class. And if you need this column defined in class (for further saving or displaying) you can create a property and mark it with a `@Column` decorator. Property name must be the same as the join column name in the table. Described in more detail [here](https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/how-to-use-relation-id-without-joining-relation)

> Creating an entity with the same id just overrides the existing one

this is an expected behaviour. When you trying to save entity with an existing Id, TypeORM recognizes this as an update, not a create

Comment: I tested your solution and I think this seems to work. Would you mind explaining why two fields are required? And it knows how to map that field to a variable via string?

Comment: The only case still failing was the first part. Creating an entity with the same id just overrides the existing one ..

Comment: yes, I was able to reproduce it with this sample repo :) https://github.com/mhcomp/setting-up-a-one-to-many-relationship-for-a-self-referencing-table/tree/master/setting-up-a-one-to-many-relationship-for-a-self-referencing-table/src

Comment: ok, one last question: The code seems to work fine but are you sure a `ManyToOne` relation should be used instead of a `OneToMany` relation?

Comment: yep, in TypeORM `@OneToMany` is an inverse side of `@ManyToOne` and cannot exist without `@ManyToOne`. Also `@OneToMany` is not required and can be ommited in this case. For example if you need "projects which follow before successor" or in other words "projects in which this project is specified as successor" then you need to use `OneToMany` as inverse side. It will look like `@OneToMany(() => Project, project => project.successor) public projects: Project[]`

Comment: btw, I don't know your requirements about successor. If a one successor can be specified in many projects, then `@ManyToOne` is right approach. Otherwise if one succesor can follow only one project, then you should use `@OneToOne` relation instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
export class RolesPermission {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'varchar', length: 36, default: 'UUID()' })
  entityId?: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => RolesPermission, (rolePermission) => rolePermission.parent)
  rolePermissions?: RolesPermission[];

  @ManyToOne(() => RolesPermission, (rolePermission) => rolePermission.rolePermissions, { nullable: true, createForeignKeyConstraints: false })
  parent?: RolesPermission;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt?: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt?: Date;}
```